# Play Framework Error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present with multi-dimensional JSON

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

So I'm trying to do a post on a webservice I've built with Play framework. I use an ajax call to make the request and post some JSON:

```
var post = $.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"http://0.0.0.0:9000/v1.0/products",
data:'{"name":"Double product fdsfdsdf","sku":"3432432432","price":{"value":"22.0","curency":{"key":"USD"}}}'
})
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
undefined
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://0.0.0.0:9000/v1.0/products. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://0.0.0.0:2333' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Here are my settings on Play:

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  /**
   * Global action composition.
   */
  override def doFilter(action: EssentialAction): EssentialAction = EssentialAction { request =>
    action.apply(request).map(_.withHeaders(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" -> "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" -> "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" -> "true"
    ))
  }
}
```

Any idea what's going on? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a preflight OPTIONS call that the browser might send first to see if there are any headers present, you may need to make sure you answer to that with correct headers.

There is a good flow chart of how CORS works here where you can see the OPTIONS request and what is supposed to happen for that:
http://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/cors_server_flowchart.png